# How to extract black and white moves separately from a Portable Game Notation (PGN) file?

Tags: python, chess, python-chess

I would like to extract the white moves and black moves made in a chess game seperately, by analyzing the PGN (Portable Game Notation) file, using Python.

**Example:**

```
1. e4 e5 2. Nf3 Nc6 3. Bb5 a6 4. Ba4 Nf6 5. O-O b5 6. Bb3 Bb7 7. d3 Be7 8. Nc3 O-O 9. a3 Nd4 10. Nxd4 exd4 11. Ne2 c5 12. Bg5 d5 13. Bxf6 Bxf6 14. Bxd5 Bxd5 15. exd5 Qxd5 16. Ng3 c4 17. Re1 Rae8 18. a4 Rxe1+ 19. Qxe1 cxd3 20. cxd3 bxa4 21. Qd1 Qb5 22. Ne4 Be7 23. Qc2 Rb8 24. Rxa4 Qxb2 25. Qxb2 Rxb2 26. g4 Rb6 27. Rxd4 Kf8 28. Rd7 Rg6 29. Kf1 Rxg4 30. Ra7 f5 31. Ng3 g6 32. Rxa6 Rh4 33. Kg2 Rd4 34. Ne2 Rxd3 35. Ng1 Rd7 36. Nf3 Kg7 37. h3 Bf6 38. Kg3 Rb7 39. Kg2 Re7 40. Ra5 Rc7 41. Rd5 Ra7 42. Rb5 Be7 43. Nd4 Rd7 44. Nf3 Rd6 45. Rb7 Kf6 46. Ra7 h6 47. Nh4 Bd8 48. Rh7 Rd2 49. Rxh6 Kg7 50. Rxg6+ Kh7 51. Nf3 Rxf2+ 52. Kxf2 Kxg6 53. Kg2 Kh5 54. Nd4 f4 55. Ne6 Bg5 56. Nxg5 Kxg5 57. Kf3 Kh4 58. Kxf4 Kxh3 1/2-1/2
```

Comment: Read it in as a string and separate using a regular expression for a number followed by a period.

Comment: If you simply analyze this game then there are other software that do not use python. Just tell me if you only want to analyze this simply by not using python

Answer (score 1):

White starts. So for each move, first is the move number, then the white move, then the black one. A basic logic to use is then:

```
s = "1. e4 e5 2. Nf3 Nc6 3. Bb5 a6 4. Ba4 Nf6 5. O-O b5 1/2-1/2"
move_numbers = s.split()[0::3]  # last element will be the game conclusion, here 1/2-1/2
white_moves = s.split()[1::3]
black_moves = s.split()[2::3]
```

Just be careful that if white made the last move, the game conclusion will be added as a black_moves. You can check whether it's the case by checking `len(s.split())`

Comment: I think you forgot parentheses after your `split` calls: `TypeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object is not subscriptable`

Comment: An optimization - `s.split()` can be saved in a variable first, and then called repeatedly. This will reduce code execution time significantly

Comment: @RobinDeSchepper you're right; thanks for edit.